replicating adobe checkmarks so that it can be edited later on as well
I want to create checkmarks like adobe in my application so that the can be edited in adobe acrobat as well. How can I do this in python
How can I get information of where adobe is storing information related to its checkmarks, i have tried looking into annotation layer.
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import NameObject, TextStringObject, DictionaryObject, ArrayObject, FloatObject, IndirectObject, BooleanObject
def add_checkmark_to_pdf(input_pdf_path, output_pdf_path, page_number, x, y, checked=True):
with open(input_pdf_path, 'rb') as input_file:
reader = PdfReader(input_file)
writer = PdfWriter()
    page = reader.pages[page_number]

    # Ensure the page has annotations
    if '/Annots' not in page:
        page['/Annots'] = ArrayObject()

    # Create a checkbox annotation
    checkbox = DictionaryObject()
    checkbox.update({
        NameObject("/Type"): NameObject("/Annot"),
        NameObject("/Subtype"): NameObject("/Widget"),
        NameObject("/Rect"): ArrayObject([FloatObject(x), FloatObject(y), FloatObject(x + 20), FloatObject(y + 20)]),  # Coordinates of the checkbox
        NameObject("/FT"): NameObject("/Btn"),
        NameObject("/T"): TextStringObject("MyCheckbox"),
        NameObject("/V"): BooleanObject(checked),  # Use BooleanObject to represent the checkbox state
        NameObject("/AS"): BooleanObject(checked),  # Use BooleanObject to represent the appearance state
        NameObject("/AP"): IndirectObject(7),  # Reference to the appearance stream
    })

    # Append the annotation to the page
    annot = IndirectObject(len(reader.pages) + len(page['/Annots']) + 1)
    page['/Annots'].append(annot)
    writer.add_object(checkbox)  # Add the annotation object to the writer

    writer.add_page(page)

    with open(output_pdf_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        writer.write(output_file)

Example usage:
add_checkmark_to_pdf("checkmark.pdf", "output.pdf", 0, 100, 100)
